# Printing integers from a file using an array

Tags: c++, arrays, file, ifstream

I'm just beginning to learn C++ and I am having some trouble with a program. It's supposed to sort numbers from an external file. I've managed to successfully code the sorting algorithm, but I am having trouble working with the external file. I am just testing some things out in a separate program to gain an understanding of how things like ifstream work. I should be able to figure out how to implement it into my program once I gain a better understanding of how it works.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>


int main() {
    using namespace std;


    int count;
    ifstream InFile;

    InFile.open ("unsorted.txt");

InFile >> count;
int numbers[count];      

for(int a = 0; a < count; a++)
    InFile >> numbers[a];
    cout << numbers << endl;
}
```

Currently, the output for this is 0x7ffc246c98e0 I am not sure why this is the case I'm just attempting to print my file of integers. Could anyone help explain what I am doing wrong? I'd be very thankful.

Comment: Variable Length Arrays are not standard C++, use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you do

```
cout << numbers << endl;
```

you print the pointer to the first element of the array.

You want

```
cout << numbers[a] << '\n';
```

to print the current element.

---

Furthermore, if that's all your program is doing, then you don't actually *need* the array. All you need is a single `int` variable:

```
int value;
for (int a = 0; a < count; ++a)
{
    InFile >> value;
    cout << value << '\n';
}
```

That also solve the problem with the variable-length array (since there isn't any).

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help! This is my first time working with this language so I really appreciate you helping me out!

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to use count variable to count the file size or something, it is where your code goes wrong. You can't count the length of the file as like as you are trying.

```
while( getline ( InFile, line ) )
{
count += line.length();
}
```

Maybe, try like this!!! 
If you use

```
InFile>>count;
```

it would try to store all the string from InFile stream to count, which is not intended.